# How to insert values using sqlite in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

i am trying to insert values.But values are not saved.This is my coding.i alredy created the database using sqlite manager.That database name is "`feedback.sqlite`". If i run the code no errors will be displayed.But if i entered the data then click the save button the data will not be saved.if i run the code "Failed to open/create database" message will be displayed on the simulator.i cant guess where the error is.please give me an idea.thanks in advance.

**Ratingviewcontroller.h**

```
@interface RatingViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {

    sqlite3 *contactDB;

    IBOutlet UITextField *Traineeid;
    IBOutlet UITextField *Trainername;
    IBOutlet UITextField *Traineename;
    IBOutlet UITextField *Rating;
    IBOutlet UILabel *status;

    NSString *dbpath;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UITextField *Traineeid;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UITextField *Trainername;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UITextField *Traineename;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UITextField *Rating;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UILabel *status;

- (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)findData:(id)sender;

@end
```

**Ratingviewcontroller.m**

```
@implementation RatingViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    // get the document directory

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory,
                                                   NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Build the path to the database file

    dbpath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:
            [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"feedback.sqlite"]];
    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:dbpath] == NO) {

        const char *db = [dbpath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(db, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK) {

            char *errMsg;
            const char *sql_stmt =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (Traineeid INTEGER "
                "PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Trainername TEXT, Traineename "
                "TEXT, Rating float)";

            if (sqlite3_exec(contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) !=
                SQLITE_OK) {

                status.text = @"Failed to create table";
            }

            sqlite3_close(contactDB);

        } else {

            status.text = @"Failed to open/create database";
        }
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)saveData:(id)sender {

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *database = [dbpath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(database, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString *insertSQL =
            [NSString stringWithFormat:
                    @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (Trainee id, Trainer name, Trainee "
                     "name,Rating) VALUES (\"%@\",\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",
                Traineeid, Trainername.text, Trainername.text, Rating.text];

        /*  NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into
                                      CONTACTS
           (Traineeid,Trainername,Traineename,Rating) values
                                      (\"%d\",\"%@\", \"%@\",
           \"%f\")",[Traineeid integerValue],
                                       Trainername, Traineename,[Rating
           float]];*/

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE) {

            status.text = @"Contact added";
            Traineeid.text = @"";
            Trainername.text = @"";
            Traineename.text = @"";
            Rating.text = @"";

        } else {

            status.text = @"Failed to add contact";
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }
}

- (void)findContact {

    const char *datapath = [dbpath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open(datapath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                  @"select Trainer name,Trainee name,Rating "
                                   "from CONTACT where Traineeid=\"%@\"",
                              Traineeid];

        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) ==
            SQLITE_OK) {

            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                NSString *trainid = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                        (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

                Traineeid.text = trainid;

                NSString *trainernme = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                        (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];

                Trainername.text = trainernme;

                NSString *traineenme = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                        (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];

                Traineename.text = traineenme;

                NSString *rat = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                        (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];

                Rating.text = rat;
                status.text = @"Match found";

            } else {

                status.text = @"Match not found";
                Traineeid.text = @"";
                Trainername.text = @"";
                Traineename.text = @"";
                Rating.text = @"";
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }

        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: Nice formatting!  Anyway I haven't looked at the code, but I bet you don't use `sqlite3_errmsg()` do you?  It's there to tell you what went wrong.

Comment: if database exists create the table the condition seems to be false if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: dbpath ] == NO) try if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: dbpath ])

Comment: Not related to your complaint, but Google "SQL injection" to see why you should not insert data values into you SQL string.  (Simply using prepared statements is not enough, if you're inserting the data values into the statements vs using value substitution.)

Answer (score -1):

try this code and also you already created the database using sqlite manager.Thats why there is no need to create the insert the values.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:dbpath]) {

        const char *db = [dbpath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(db, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK) {

            char *errMsg;

            const char *sql_stmt =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (Traineeid INTEGER "
                "PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Trainername TEXT, Traineename "
                "TEXT, Rating float)";

            if (sqlite3_exec(contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) !=
                SQLITE_OK) {

                status.text = @"Failed to create table";
            }

            sqlite3_close(contactDB);

        } else {

            status.text = @"Failed to open/create database";
        }
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```